# Second monitor not working

Tags: display

Second monitor works only when I lock the PC and the lock screen is on. But when I log in the monitor doesn't work, the display doesn't detect any source. The monitor is detected in Settings, but when I try to toggle the monitor on, the toggle button just goes back to off state. It won't let me toggle it on.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Laptop or desktop? How do you connect the second monitor to your computer?

Comment: It's desktop, it's connected via HDMI. But it worked now after disconnecting HDMI and starting the OS and then connceting HDMI again.

Comment: I hav e had this periodically, connecting via VGA.  no idea what triggers it or how to fix other than reconnecting :/

Comment: It can get really annoying. I hope it gets fixed soon. Mod for Elementary OS IRC (he is also dev for EOS) said some dev will look at this problem when I linked him this question.

Comment: I have same problem too, my second monitor undetected after i logged into my user account.
I don't know how to reset second monitor setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked now after disconnecting HDMI and starting the OS and then connceting HDMI again

Comment: What's up with down vote? I hope this can help others with same problem.